# Github - banding domain issue

Tags: git, github, hexo

In local test ,my web test was ok.

than I want to use custom domain(317cpan.com) to bind my GitHub pages (ekoopgj.github.io)

[image]

I create a CNAME file in my repo on GitHub:

```
$ cat CNAME
317cpan.com
```

and in Repo setting pages I filled the custom domain with 317cpan,com， then SAVE.

[image]

also in DNS provider I add resolution for my githubpages by A record

[image]

and I also can see my custom domain published in GitHub pages

√ Your site is published at http://317cpan.com/

But when I click the http://317cpan.com/, the web pages comes error:

```
403 forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I have confused with it for a long time...

At last , what you need to do is just wait , because it need take time for DNS server to resolve the custom domain.(when I finish writing the question on Stack Over flow, the link can open successfully. )

Answer (score 1):

I find the final reason : Because I used company network to connect my custom domain, and intranet was restricted to visit GitHub, So any domain that bind to Github Pages will be forbidden to visit. Now I visit the custom domain by my cellphone are OK , because my cellphone not connect to my company network.

Comment: Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that solved your problem (even if it's your own - in this case you have to wait 48 hours though) instead of adding *solved* to the question title. Thank you :-)